# Send Mail to user, when End date is less than 4 days

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, email

I have a Data Sheet type list, where I have items with fields - Title, Start Date, End Date, Person allocated, and a comment column.

Now how can I create a workflow to trigger, when the elements end date is due within 4 days. And the mail should go to the person allocated, with comment column fields.

I am not sure how to send mail, only when the end date is due with in 4 days. And how to send it to the person in the allocated column!!

Please help me on this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a custom timer job which triggers an email when this condition is met.

1. Create a custom timer job which checks the list for all items end date.
2. If the end date is duw within 4 days, get the person allocated from the list item and get his email id.
3. Trigger an email with the person's email id with the comments column as the matter.

You can schedule the timer job to check the site for each 5 minutes or so (In the central admin), based on the requirement.

Comment: Thanks Deepu bayya, How ever, how can I create a timer job in Sharepoint!! Do I need to use some Windows Service!!

Comment: I shall send you some sample code while I reach home..that should help you to start with..

Comment: Hi, Create a class which extends the class SPJobDefinition... and you will have to write your code in the method 'Execute'.. You can search in google... lots of example are available.. for implementing Timer jobs in SharePoint

Comment: Thanks paddy, Deepu had sent me a sample snippet, let me try with that and will let you know the progress!!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom expiration policy and bind it to the list in the Information management policy settings of the list.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262112(v=office.12).aspx

This is for 2007 but the same rules apply.